# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class when I use reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am new to Java reflection. I tried to call one method of my `DAO` Class using reflection, and I got the below mentioned error of illegal argument exception. Below is my code. My method contains two arguments: one is Dossier bean object and another is `sessionfactory` object. I got this error when I invoke my method. I searched lot on net but did not find the proper solution.

```
public String getDossierDetail(HttpSession session,DoerDAO doerDao,SessionFactory sessionFactory,String requestedUser) throws ClassNotFoundException{
    log.info("(getDossierDetail)Execution starts");
    ReviewerOne reviewer = new ReviewerOne();
    String message = "";        
    DoerDAO doerDaoInt = new DoerDAO();
    try{
        List<Dossier> dossierDetail = (List<Dossier>) session.getAttribute(ObjectConstant.dossierDetailBean);
        System.out.println("dossierDetail: "+dossierDetail.size()+"product nm: "+dossierDetail.get(0).getProductName()+"requested User: "+requestedUser);
        Method method =  DoerDAO.class.getDeclaredMethod(requestedUser,Dossier.class,SessionFactory.class);         
         method.invoke(dossierDetail.get(0), sessionFactory);           
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error("(getDossierDetail)Error is: ",e);            
        message = e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
    return message;
}
```

my requestedUser value is :: getReviewerOneDetail.

/******** DoerDao method ****************/

```
public void getReviewerOneDetail(Dossier dossierBean,SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    log.info("(getReviewerOneDetail)Execution starts.");



    try{

        System.out.println("in reviewer one detail....");

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error("(getReviewerOneDetail)Error is: ",e);
    }


}
```

Comment: This smells like [an XY problem.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/133242) Why are you using reflection to call a method? What is the bigger task you're trying to solve? Why can't you use a normal method call?

Comment: Could you show the Exception and in which line it occurs?

Comment: Bro i have so many method to call using method name. but i got stuck in first invocation. so if this get solve i will add more methods.

Comment: @treeno :: it occurs when i invoke my method.method.invoke(dossierDetail.get(0), sessionFactory);

Comment: @PratikJoshi what's output of line  `System.out.println("dossierDetail: "+dossierDetail.size()+"product nm: "+dossierDetail.get(0).getProductName()+"requested User: "+requestedUser);`

Comment: Pratik, your code calls via reflection the method with the name as passed in the `requestedUser` variable. Is this what you need?

Comment: @dbw it gives proper output what i want. Every object prints the value which are required.

Comment: @AndreiNicusan yeah...  this is what i want.

Comment: I think you have a method in DoerDao that is named <requestedUser>, but the parameter-types don't fit to Dossier.class,SessionFactory.class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short version: You are missing the first argument in your call to `invoke`.

Long version: You are calling

```
Method method = DoerDAO.class.getDeclaredMethod(requestedUser,
   Dossier.class,
   SessionFactory.class);
```

Let's say that the value of `requestedUser` is `getReviewerOneDetail`, then you'd look up the method

```
getReviewerOneDetail(Dossier arg0, SessionFactory arg1)
```

Next you call

```
method.invoke(dossierDetail.get(0), sessionFactory);
```

The [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) states that invoke gets as first parameter the instance(!) of the class to call the method on and as second, third, ... parameters the actual parameters for your invocation.

So, what you actually trying to call in your code, is

```
dossierDetail.get(0).getReviewerOneDetail(sessionFactory);
```

which does neither match the method signature (1 parameter vs. 2 parameters), nor the instance type on which the method is called (`Dossier` instead of `DoerDAO`).

Because you acquire the `Method` from the `DoerDAO` class, I guess what you intended to write there, was actually:

```
method.invoke(doerDao, dossierDetail.get(0), sessionFactory);
```

This would translate to

```
doerDao.getReviewerOneDetail(dossierDetail.get(0), sessionFactory);
```

Comment: Bro you are champ... I was looking for it to get solved since morning. great work man.